# Linebreak in TextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, textbox, line-breaks

How can I get a linebreak in TextBox in WP7? I'm developing social-based app(like facebook) and if I set AcceptReturn=true, it gives me a visual(ui) linebreak, but when I send this text to the server I can see that there is no linebreak. Please help me with this problem. I've tried

```
void whatsend_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) {
      if (e.Key == Key.Enter) {
        whatsend.Text +="\r";//or /n,&#13;
      }
    }
```

but with no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows uses `\r\n` for line breaks, not `\r`, but that's irrelevant; use `Environment.NewLine` instead.

Also, per the docs:

> true if the ENTER key creates a new line of text **in a multiline version of the control**; false if the ENTER key activates the default button for the form. The default is false.

Did you set `MultiLine` to `true`?

EDIT:  Ahhh, WP7... [here is an article I found](http://shareourideas.com/2011/01/10/multiline-textbox-in-windows-phone-7/) which attempts to create a multi-line textbox in WP7.

Comment: @wsevendays: Is your textbox multi-line, i.e., did you set `MultiLine = true`?  If not then `AcceptsReturn` has no effect per the documentation.

Comment: TextBox control in WP7 doesn't have "MultiLine" value.

Comment: When I press return(enter) key I see that textbox adds new line, but when I send this text to server it doesn't show that the text contains linebreak.

Comment: All is ok. The problem was in server.

Answer (score 2):

Environment.NewLine if its the same as normal development.

Comment: This is so much longer than "\r\n" though, and bulks up your code quite a bit if you have a lot of them. What's the difference, and why wouldn't you just use "\r\n"?

Comment: Who cares if it is more verbose?  It would have fixed your bug as you used the wrong newline character.  It is a constant, it could potentially change (even if that's unlikely), just use it.  No one cares how short your code is, they care if it actually works.  If you don't like typing it then store it in a variable first; `var nl = Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: When I send text, the linebreak in textbox shows as space and newline inserts in the beginning of textbox, not at the end.

Answer (score 2):

just add below scope to xaml code:

```
AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"
```

something like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="InputText" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WP7 but Windows in general uses "`\r\n`" (i.e. both chars one after the other) to signify a line break.

If you append both to your text, does it solve your problem?

Having said that, I'm surprised that typed line breaks are being removed from the textbox. When you say the text isn't viewable on the server, what do you mean? Is it that the text isn't sent to and / or recorded on the server or that your method of display on the server isn't showing it?

Comment: The text in the dialog(let it be service such as facebook) displays without linebreak, only with space.